# Setup OpenGL on X11

Tags: c++, opengl, x11

I have an `Window` identifier for X11 Window. I didn't setup this window, I just can get its id (and I suppose, `visual` id). How can I setup OpenGL context for this window?

In particular, I want to use `glXMakeCurrent`, but this function receives `Display` and `GLXContext` objects. I can create context using `glXCreateContext(display, vi, 0, GL_TRUE);` but again I need in `Display` and `XVisualInfo` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a OpenGL context on a X11 window is covered by one of my code examples (based upon an example by FTB/fungus), with the notable difference that is uses FBConfig over a regular Visual.

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c

That you're given only a Window, but not a Display is a problem. You can't just go around assume the window being on the default display, so whereever you get that Window from, it also *must* give you the corresponding Display connection as well. Just passing around Window IDs is a failure in API design, when it comes to X11.

Answer (score 3):

This code fully creates a window, and initializes the opengl context.

```
Display *dpy( XOpenDisplay( NULL );
int screen = XDefaultScreen( dpy );
const int fbCfgAttribslist[] =
        {
            GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
            GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
            None
        };
int nElements = 0;
GLXFBConfig * glxfbCfg = glXChooseFBConfig( dpy,
                                      screen,
                                      fbCfgAttribslist,
                                      & nElements );

const int pfbCfg[] =
        {
            GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH,
            GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
            GLX_PRESERVED_CONTENTS, True,
            GLX_LARGEST_PBUFFER, False,
            None
        };
GLXPbuffer pBufferId = glXCreatePbuffer( dpy, glxfbCfg[ 0 ], pfbCfg );


XVisualInfo * visInfo = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( dpy, glxfbCfg[ 0 ] );

GLXContext  glCtx = glXCreateContext( dpy, visInfo, NULL, True );


glXMakeContextCurrent( dpy,
                       pBufferId,
                       pBufferId,
                       glCtx );
```

Actually this is setting up a pbuffer, not a window, but in your case, since you got window created, and visuals set, you can just skip the first part, and go on with the opengl context creation.