# Using openGL inside a browser plugin using FireBreath

Tags: linux, opengl, firebreath, browser-plugin

I went through the firebreath tutorial a few times, and things seem to work well for me.
I managed to create a simple plugin on linux and to draw in it using gtk.

What I want to accomplish however is to draw using openGL and that is not being covered in the firebreath tutorial, not for linux that is.
They do have [something for windows](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/OpenGL+Plugin) but looking through the code you realize it does not help for a linux solution.

What I'm currently looking for is how to create the openGL context from `PluginWindowX11`.
The `PluginWindowWin` returns a `HWND` object which can be then used to initialize the openGL context under windows, but the linux equivalent (`PluginWindowX11)` only returns Gtk objects from which I don't know how to create the openGL context.

I found this thread: [using OpenGl in npapi plugin ( FireBreath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873981/using-opengl-in-npapi-plugin-firebreath) which lacks any information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You have to create opengl context on the X11 window you get. Rest will be same as the opengl sample for windows. This might be what your are looking for - [Setup OpenGL on X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856820/setup-opengl-on-x11)

Comment: Thanks, seems like much info on using openGL on X11, but that's not my problem, it's more related to firebreath, as I understand I need to somehow create the OG content from the PluginWindow, or PluginWindowX11.